# SIGTERM does not reach node script when docker runs it with `/bin/sh -c`

Tags: linux, node.js, docker, docker-compose

When my Dockerfile ends with

```
CMD node .
```

docker runs that container with the command `/bin/sh -c "node ."` instead of simply `node .` (I know, I could do that with `CMD ["node", "."]`).

I thought that this behavior is actually nice, since it means that inside the container `PID1` is `/bin/sh` and not my humble node script.

If I understand correctly `PID1` is responsible for reaping orphaned zombie processes, and I don't really wan't to be responsible for that... So if `/bin/sh` could do that, that would be nice. (I actually thought that this is the reason why docker does rewrite my `CMD`).

The problem is that when I send a `SIGTERM` to the container (started with `/bin/sh -c "node ."`), either via `docker-composer stop` or `docker-composer kill -s SIGTERM`, the signal doesn't reach my `node` process and therefore it get's forcefully killed everytime with a `SIGKILL` after the 10 seconds grace period. Not nice.

Is there a way to have someone manage my zombies and have my node instance receive the signals sent by docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are tools designed to solve this problem:

- https://github.com/yelp/dumb-init
- https://github.com/krallin/tini

I think if you only have a single process, all you need to do is explicitly handle the signal with a signal handler, which bash doesn't do for you.

Using the `["node", "."]` syntax, you could use https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events and just have it exit on SIGTERM. I believe that would be enough.

Or using a bash script you can use `trap "exit 0" TERM`

You could also use a process supervisor like http://skarnet.org/software/s6/

Answer (score 8):

I think you have to understand the roles of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, and use the `ENTRYPOINT`(exec form) way in your `Dockerfile`.

`ENTRYPOINT`, which specifies the starting executable of the container, is the core part of a Docker container. Every container **MUST** have an entrypoint to decide where to start. By default the value is `/bin/bash -c`. In addition, everything set by `CMD` would be appended to `ENTRYPOINT` as arguments.

Therefore, if you failed to specify `ENTRYPOINT` in your `Dockerfile`, the actual entrypoint would be `/bin/bash -c {your_command_in_CMD}`, which unfortunately **DOES NOT** pass signals.

`ENTRYPOINT` have two forms: *exec form* and *shell form*

- exec form: ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]
- shell form: command param1 param2

As the [Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) pointed out: exec form is recommended, and shell form has the disadvantage that *command* is executed by `/bin/bash -c`, which might not work well with signals:

> The *shell form* prevents any `CMD` or `run` command line arguments from being used, but has the disadvantage that your `ENTRYPOINT` will be started as a subcommand of `/bin/sh -c`, which does not pass signals. This means that the executable will not be the container’s `PID 1` - and *will not* receive Unix signals - so your executable will not receive a `SIGTERM` from `docker stop <container>`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for the PID1 problem:

The Dockerfile ends with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

Or leave ENTRYPOINT completely out of your Dockerfile. The default is `/bin/sh -c`.

Than I run with this shell script, which has the filename of `node` and have `chmod +x`:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run --rm -it -p 8083:80 -v $HOME/node/work/:/root/node/:rw node_node "echo pid1 > /dev/null && node $@"
```

The trick is `"echo pid1 > /dev/null && node $@"` which is the command. `$@` is a shell script to accept user input from command line.

`echo` will trap PID1 and sending output to `/dev/null`.

For example `./node -v` will return the version of Node.js inside the running container.

Running a webserver with `./node /root/node/hello-world.js` command, CTRL+C will work again.

[Here](https://github.com/DJviolin/Node.js-Development-Environment) is my Dockerised Node.js development environment.

**EDIT:**

Totally crazy idea, but add this `node` named bash script to the $PATH. So on the host, you can type `node -v` instead of `./node -v`. And you run node in a Docker container which is totally looks like it was installed on the host. :)