# Docker /bin/sh propagates SIGTERM to java app when it shouldn't

Tags: java, bash, docker

After reading a bunch of articles about bash not propagating SIGTERM to its children, I thought that having entrypoint of `/bin/sh -c java ...` will cause problems and SIGTERM won't be propagated to `java` process, but it actually does and shutdown hooks run. Contrary to that, if I run `/bin/sh -c sleep ...` then it wont be terminated with SIGTERM.

NB: in both cases I see actual process being PID 1 (not bash)

How can this be explained?

Comment: Why `/bin/sh -c java` could cause problem? Is this a question regarding to some research or do you have errors on your container?

Comment: There are bunch of answers which say that signal shouldn't be propagated, but in my case it does. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34446294/3575763